# Codeigniter, domain to a certain area of the site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I'm not a very experienced programmer, and am using CodeIgniter for second time.

Suppose I have www.domain1.com. So I will have, say 3 controllers /area1, /area2, /area3. Users can access them as www.domain1.com/area1 etc. if I set the base URL as www.domain1.com. But my problem is, the client wants a certain area of the web, say area2, working as a microsite, in its own domain, so he wants to access area2 with www.domain2.com.

I don't know how to get this working with CodeIgniter. Suppose he registers www.domain2.com and set it pointing to the same DNS, server etc. How can I get CodeIgnitor to execute the controller area2 when the URL www.domain2.com is accessed?

Maybe changing `$config['base-url']`? Routing? `.htaccess`? Please, if you have solved this, examples of code involved would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I will put example of the site I want to get.

I have one normal installation of CodeIgniter (external host, I can't access `httpd.conf`) It is on one machine, and the root of the site should be accessed by www.domain1.com

All domain are outside registered to. So I have the home controller, which shows me the main page view. And suppose the site have 3 areas /area1, /area2 /area3, with their correspondent controllers, showing these areas views.

My client want to emphasize one of the areas, the one that controller /area2 shows, and he want use a different domain for that area, www.domain2.com

What can I do so that when the user browse to www.domain2.com, CI redirects them to www.domain1.com/area2? Could I, for example, modify `$config['base_url']` according the received URL, or is that impossible? Do I need to modify the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: if i am right the controller for the area2 is on the same domain as all other controller?

Comment: all controllers all on same folder on same hosting, just one phisical machine, one hosting)

Comment: i just want to be able to view /area2 controler result accesing with a different domain name that the one i access the codeigniter root.

Comment: Can you try to shorten your question to something less long winded? Half the time it's difficult trying to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: You are right Yi, excuse me, it is long because i tried to explain details to other posters.

Comment: And thanks for the edit, english is not muy native languaje and I don't use it frecuently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found a solution that seems to work, very easy to be honest:

Modify `routes.php`:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="www.domain2.com") {
    $route['default_controller'] = "area2"; 
}
```

No need for mod rewrite.

Comment: I like this one, you also need to make sure domain1.com can't access area2, eg. add: if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="www.domain1.com"){$route['area2']="diff_controller";}

Comment: You should accept an answer for your questions, by clicking on the green checkmark beside each answer - this will mark the question as solved, and will give a small reward to the asker and answerer for their trouble. In this case, since you solved you're own problem, you should accept this answer.

Comment: this is the best solution and something I am using right now also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful link....
http://www.askaboutphp.com/88/codeigniter-setting-up-multiple-sites-on-one-install.html
Never actually done this myself, but this seems to be the way to go about it without having two ci installs.  Good luck.

Comment: This is not really my case, so i dont want to have diffreent aplications like he does. I just want to access a part of my only aplication (it is a part of the whole web anyway) with a different domain. Check example on my edit.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely need to go the mod_rewrite way

Comment: I will try studing mod_rewrite posibilities then

Answer (score -1):

the first solution that comes to my mind is to use Apache mod_rewrite, but as far as I know that would work only for internal redirects (i.e. resources residing on the same server/domain).

What about using an iframe? You could set up domain2.com home page with a full-page iframe that takes it's content from domain1.com/area2.

Comment: I will try studing mod_rewrite posibilities then. The iframe idea is a good pont too, will try that too.